Zeros of the derivative of the characteristic polynomial of a unitary matrix
There's a productive analogy between the zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ and the zeros of the characteristic polynomial $p(z)$ of a unitary matrix $A$, and even the zeros of their respective derivatives.  In this analogy the critical line $\text{re}(s)=1/2$  corresponds to the unit circle $|z|=1$.  More precisely, the analogy relates zeros of $\zeta(s)$ at height $T$ in the critical strip  and zeros of $p(z)$ when $A$ is $n$ by $n$, for $n\approx \log(T)$.  For simplicity we will assume the Riemann Hypothesis, in the strong form that the zeros are also simple.
In 1998, Soundararajan showed that if $1/2+i\gamma^-$, $1/2+i\gamma^+$ are consecutive zeros of $\zeta(s)$, $T=(\gamma^++\gamma^-)/2$, then there is at most one zero $\rho^\prime$ in the box
$$
\{s=\sigma+it\,|\, 1/2<\sigma<1/2+1/\log T,\, \gamma^-\le t\le \gamma^+\}.
$$
Is there an analog of this?  For generality we state the question for polynomials without reference to any matrix:  Suppose $p(z)$ is degree $n$ with all its roots on the unit circle.  Let $\exp(i\theta^-)$, $\exp(i\theta^+)$ be consecutive roots, in the obvious sense of the counterclockwise orientation on the unit circle.  Is there a theorem that $p^\prime(z)$ has at most one root on the angular sector
$$
\{\theta^-\le\arg(z)\le\theta^+,\, 1-1/n<|z|<1\}?
$$

Have a look at MR4728711 (Ge-Gonek, Critical points of polynomials with roots on the unit circle. IMRN, 2024). The discussion on page 5 seems particularly relevant to your question.
